# How to detect if Qt Application(WIN & MAC) is hung

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, freeze

I have a desktop Qt application(For Windows and MAC) written in C++. We receive reports and feedbacks that the application has hung, and must be forcefully terminated.
How to detect if the Application is hung ?
so that we can at-least gather additional metric about the number of times the Application hangs.

Is it possible to achieve within the application ?
Or Can we create a separate executable **process** which polls the Application periodically and reports the metric if the Application hangs?

Note: For windows i came to know about "**SendMessageTimeout()**" API can this be used by the **process** to poll the Application ?

Also any similar available for MAC ?

Comment: On Windows there's also [IsHungAppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ishungappwindow) that's a bit more robust in determining a hung application than `SendMessageTimeout`. Either one needs to be called from a thread other than the GUI thread, ideally a separate process.

Comment: Is there any similar for MAC?
Also does Qt have any support for identifying such?